# Добавить свою позицию(menuitem) в контекстное меню в MS Project 2016 (VSTO)

Tags: c#, vsto

Нужно добавить в стандартное контекстное меню свой пункт меню. На диаграмме Ганта в MS Project 2016 через VSTO.
Рою интернет 2й день не получается.
Я так понимаю нужно знать ID контекстного меню.
foreach выдает 43 вариантов commandbar (в примере кода индекс 1 менял на от 1 до 43)
Где то появляется меню но не в контексте. А на верхней панели.

вот примерный код.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject.Application();

          CommandBar popupCommandBar = app.CommandBars[1];
            var commandBarButton = (CommandBarButton)popupCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true);
            commandBarButton.Caption = "Hello !!!";
            commandBarButton.FaceId = 356;
            commandBarButton.Tag = "HELLO_TAG";
```

Важно. Проджект на русском.
Но это один из многих вариантов найденых в инете.
Что не так делаю?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вся моя ошибка была в том что я использовал визуальный ribbon. Который считается устаревшим. Нужно использовать Ribbon XML Там меню делается через XML теги. И нельзя смешивать. Когда один ribbon визуальный а второй XML.Хотя странно что в Excel2016 CommandBar работает правильно а в Project2016 он не работает с контекстным типом меню. По крайней мере у меня не получилось.

Вот так будет выглядеть контекстное меню которое нужно добавить в конец XML Ribbon

```
<contextMenus>
            <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuTaskCell">
                <menuSeparator/>
                <button id="MyMenuItem"  label="My Menu Item" onAction="Button_Click"  getImage="GetImage" />
                <menu id="MySubMenu" label="My Submenu" >
                    <button id="MyButton2" label="Button on submenu" />
                </menu>
            </contextMenu>
        </contextMenus>
```